# Detecting when a window is opened

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Is there an event or a way to detect when a window is opened/ reopened ?

I have two windows/frames, I am switching between them using the following code:

```
self.frame1.withdraw()
self.frame2.deiconify()
```

I have used this protocole to detect when a frame is closer:

```
self.frame.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)
```

I have been looking into these protocols, I found this document, but it seems like there are only three protocols ? and there isn't one for when a window is opened ?
https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xorg-docs/specs/ICCCM/icccm.html

Edit: Module1 hosts frame1 and Object2 hosts frame2. All windows are created when the code is executed, but they are hidden and only the main window is visible. I switch between frames with withdraw() and deiconify(). I want that Module1 performs some action when frame1 is made visible.

Comment: It's your own code that creates the new window. Why do you need a notification?

Comment: @BryanOakley I don't need notification for 'creating' the window. but rather for showing it. I might have forgot to point that each frame is done in a different object.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind to the `<Map>` event to be notified when a window is made visible.

```
def notify(event):
    print("window was mapped: %s" % event.widget)

window = tk.Toplevel(...)
window.bind("<Map>", notify)
```

From the official tk documentation:

> Windows are created in the unmapped state. Top-level windows become mapped when they transition to the normal state, and are unmapped in the withdrawn and iconic states. Other windows become mapped when they are placed under control of a geometry manager (for example pack or grid).
>
> A window is viewable only if it and all of its ancestors are mapped. Note that geometry managers typically do not map their children until they have been mapped themselves, and unmap all children when they become unmapped; hence in Tk Map and Unmap events indicate whether or not a window is viewable.